# SSL handshake keeps failing even after adding certificates to local truststore

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificates

When executing

```
wget https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf
```

I have this error:

```
--2020-06-03 20:55:06--  https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf
Resolving docs.conda.io (docs.conda.io)... 104.31.71.166, 104.31.70.166, 172.67.149.185, ...
Connecting to docs.conda.io (docs.conda.io)|104.31.71.166|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify docs.conda.io's certificate, issued by ‘CN=SSL-SG1-GFRPA2,OU=Operations,O=Cloud Services,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to docs.conda.io insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

The certificates chain in the URL above contains 4 certificates.

What I have tried to solve this problem:

0) Extract the 4 certificates in the chain, from chrome when opening the url

1) Just to ensure not missing certificates, I put all the 4 certificates (namely `conda1.crt`, `conda2.crt`, `conda3.crt`, `conda4.crt`) in `/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/` by doing `sudo cp conda*.crt /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/`

2) `sudo vi /etc/ca-certificates.conf` and append `mozilla/conda1.crt`, `mozilla/conda2.crt`, `mozilla/conda3.crt`, `mozilla/conda4.crt` at the end

3) run `sudo update-ca-certificates -f`

4) I can see symbolic link created under /etc/ssl/certs which looks like: `conda1.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/conda1.crt`, `conda2.pem -> /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/conda2.crt`, etc.

Verification:

```
openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -CAfile conda1.pem conda2.pem
conda2.pem: OK

openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -CAfile conda2.pem conda3.pem
conda3.pem: OK

openssl verify -no-CAfile -no-CApath -partial_chain -CAfile conda3.pem conda4.pem
conda4.pem: OK
```

Result: still fail with wget

**P.S.**
I am facing this ssl problem in many aspects and many urls since a month ago (no problem before):

1. I cannot do conda search a_package
2. I cannot do requests.get(url) in python code
3. I cannot open it in a browser within my ubuntu system (can only access in windows)
4. I cannot do fromUrl in scala

It seems the problem is not only due to one or two certificates, instead, it's a systematic problem in my ubuntu system. Looks like it's missing a list of certificates in my truststore.

`uname` => Linux user 5.3.0-53-generic #47~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 7 13:10:50 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I'm using Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: Did you try like the error states?  `wget --no-check-certificate https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/4.6.0/_downloads/52a95608c49671267e40c689e0bc00ca/conda-cheatsheet.pdf`  Also, if you run `wget --version` what version are you running and also does it show that it was compiled with SSL?

Comment: @Terrance Thanks. It works with `--no-check-certificate` but this is not what I want. Regarding version `wget --version
GNU Wget 1.19.4 built on linux-gnu.`

Comment: Understandable.  Not sure why yours isn't supporting SSL but maybe try reinstalling `wget` by running `sudo apt install --reinstall wget` then when you check the version, pay attention to the next line under the version number and see if it shows `-cares +digest -gpgme +https +ipv6 +iri +large-file -metalink +nls +ntlm +opie +psl +ssl/openssl` as the `+ssl/openssl` is the important part.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out the cause but not the solution. The problem is not in wget, but the Bluecoat service that intercepts in the middle. However, I have installed the CA provided by Bluecoat in the truststore as well, it's still failing.